# Term for simulation data structure

Tags: data-structures, simulation, observer-pattern

I've seen a data structure before used for simulation, but I'm unsure of any keywords to find more information about it.

The data structure is basically a "sign up sheet" for objects to receive updates as time goes on. It's similar to an Observer pattern. My plan is to use it for objects in a game to update ever couple of seconds rather than every tick.

Is there a name for this particular data structure, or if not, how can I implement something like this optimally?

Comment: It's usually called the "publish-subscribe pattern".  There are are lots and lots of different ways to implement it, through.  What language are you working in?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're thinking of the "listener pattern" described in the paper [Building Complex Models with LEGOS (Listener Event Graph Objects)](http://informs-sim.org/wsc02papers/094.pdf)?